# could not execute a stored procedure(using DAAB) from a client(aspx page) to a wcf service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, enterprise-library

i am trying to store data to sql database from a asp.net client website through a stored procedure(using DAAB) in a wcf service hosted in a asp.net empty website.When i try to store data to the DB i get the following error:

```
 **

 - The server was unable to process the request due to an internal
   error.  For more information about the error, either turn on
   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
   or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in
   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn
   on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
   inspect the server trace logs.

**
```

When i try to debug i get the following exception: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "" in the code--

```
 Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("MyInstance");
```

where my app.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true"/>
  </configSections>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="MyInstance"/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyInstance" connectionString="Data Source=BLRKDAS307581\KD;Integrated Security=True;User ID=SAPIENT\kdas3;Password=ilove0LINUX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You say the configuration is from app.config...do you mean web.config?

Comment: I have created a class library that contains the database transactions  which has the necessary DB configurations. Code in the cs file looks like: string result;
 Databasedb=EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>"MyInstance");DbCommand cmdObj = db.GetStoredProcCommand("AddtoDB");
db.AddInParameter(cmdObj, "@FirstName", DbType.String, cust.FirstName);
            ...........db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmdObj);result = db.GetParameterValue(cmdObj, "@strMessage").ToString();return result;
            
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

By default EnterpriseLibraryContainer is going to read it's configuration from web.config for a WCF service running under ASP.NET.  The configuration information should go in web.config unless you are doing some advanced configuration options (e.g. FileConfigurationSource, redirected sections, manually loading configuration files, etc.).

Comment: I copied the contents of the app.config to the web.config. But now i get the following error!! System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>.....

Comment: I would just add the Enterprise Library configuration to the web.config; it sounds like the WCF configuration is now incorrect (was it removed?).

Comment: i added the Ent Lib Config to the web.config. I dint remove it from the app.config.